# how to avoid video jumping to a new location in a webpage designed using html 5?

Tags: html, video, google-chrome, html5-video

I have included a video (using html 5) from my hard disk into a html file (called Empty.html). I load this file(Empty.html) into a frame of another html file. But, when i click the play button in the browser(chrome) the video jumps to a new location(leftmost of chrome) within the browser and plays.

I am attaching the screenshots below. Can someone please help me resolve this issue ?

The code below is the one used by me for inserting the video

```
<video poster="images/vlcsnap-00001.jpg" height="240" width="320"  draggable="false" 
controls="controls">
<source type="video/mp4" src="videos/How nuclear energy works(360p_H.264-AAC).mp4"/>
</video>
```

[image: Before clicking the play button in the browser]

[image: After clicking the play button in the browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome. I would recommend [reporting a bug to the Chromium project](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines), including a minimal sample file (or files) that demonstrate the problem.